# How much curve should be shifted to minimize the difference using fminsearch

Tags: matlab, optimization, fminsearch

I have two data sets and if I plot them then they appear like sin waves as you can see [image: below]

I want to move one curve in order to overlap on other one. I want to using fminsearch to find a shift to minimize their difference. I have numerical data and I am not getting how to use fminsearch with available information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have two data sets as vectors of `n` elements `red` and `blue` each is an `n`-by-1 vector.
Then, given an integer shift `delta` you can use [`circshift`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html) to shift one of the signals:

```
shifted = circshift( red, delta );
```

Now you can use this to define your objective function in [`fminsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html):

```
delta = fminsearch( @( x ) sum( ( blue(:) - circshift( red(:), round(x) ) ).^2 ), 20 );
```

Note that `fminsearch` heavily depends on the initial value `x0`, changing this value may have *significant* effect on the quality of the recovered `delta`.

Here's an example

```
 th = 0:.01:2*pi;
 blue = sin( th ); % orig signal
 green = sin( th + .5 ); % shifted signal
 delta = fminsearch( @( x ) sum( ( blue(:) - circshift( green(:), round(x) ) ).^2 ), 20 );
 % display results
 figure;
 plot( [blue;green]', 'LineWidth', 2 );
 hold all;
 plot( circshift( green(:), round(delta) ), '--r', 'LineWidth', 1.5 );
 legend({'orig signal','shifted signal','after recovering \delta'});
```

The recovered value of `delta` in this example is `50`,
and the output is
[image]

Comment: I have a comment about this line ( plot( circshift( green(:), round(delta) ), '--r', 'LineWidth', 1.5 );)

Comment: @User1551892 what is your comment?

Comment: sorry, I thought that I did not submit my commit somehow I did it. you are not using the original x-axis values and due to which both curves are 100% overlapping. However, if you use the fixed x-axis then parts of curves will not overlap. Its plotting related issue. Thanks a lot for explaining the solution in a nice way. I was confused how to use numeric values in fminsearch function.